back to back scr circuit
I’m working on a circuit that involves an EL3063 optocoupler and a 25TTS12 SCR. The circuit is designed to control an AC load, and I've included a schematic (attached below) for reference.
Problem:The issue I’m facing is that the SCR labeled D2 in the schematic keeps getting damaged after a short period of use. I’m not sure what’s causing this problem, and I would appreciate any guidance.
Circuit Details:
ZCD Optocoupler: EL3063
SCR: 25TTS12 (D2)
Gate Resistor (R7): 330 ohm, 1/2W
Snubber Circuit: 19.5 ohm, 4W resistors(39 ohm 2W parallel) and 0.1uF, 310VAC capacitor (R16, R3, D1, C1)
Other Components: As shown in the attached schematic
Symptoms:The SCR (D2) seems to work initially, but after some time, it gets damaged. I’ve already tried replacing it, but the problem persists.
What I’ve Tried:
I am applying 230v ac to h4 and h3 is connected with 100uf 310vac starting capacitor in series with auxiliary winding of single phase motor 0.5HP.I’ve checked for any obvious short circuits or incorrect connections.Replaced the SCR with a new one, but it also got damaged after some time.
Verified that the gate resistor value is correct.
Request:Could someone help me identify why the SCR is getting damaged? Is there something wrong with the component values or the circuit design? Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Why not use a triac instead of two SCRs?

first i try with triac  but the same issue happen in that triac get damaged .

Does the SCR failure occur at switching or after some time with the motor running?

Did you try with an ohmic load (same active power) first ? Try with R7 higher.

scr failure occur after some time with motor running also its work perfectly with ohmic load

Snubber seems too "low" (more oscillations ?). What is the oscillogram of current?

in triac circuit also work fine with resistive load, in that circuit the snubber value is 39 ohm with 0.22uf 310vac x2 capacitor

The current start could be 10-25 Aeff for 0.1-0.4 s ... Are you sure for 100 uF starting capacitor ? I have read somewhere ... 10 uF / A ...

should i have to change 1n4007 with 1n4148 or 1n4001??
